# Check the family of a Typeface object in Android

Tags: java, android, typeface

Is it possible to check what family a [Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) object is using in Android API 8?

I am creating the Typeface on a Paint object like so

```
//Simplified code, the user actually selects the family and style from a list
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD));
```

I would later like to be able to check the family like so

```
Typeface tf= paint.getTypeface();

if (tf.equals(Typeface.DEFAULT) || tf.equals(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD)) {
    //do something
} else if (...) {
    //do something else
}
```

This does not work as they are not the same object, I have also tried `tf == value` but again the same result. The Typeface object does not appear to expose anything useful to help with family detection, is there a workaround for this? I only need to detect the basic Android Typefaces (SERIF, SANS-SERIF, DEFAULT, MONOSPACE etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not readily. The key to the family is a `native_instance` `int`, which is package-private and is not directly exposed, as you can see in [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Typeface.java).

There are various nasty ways of getting at that information, which may or may not work on all devices and all past/present/future versions of Android.

Perhaps you could create your own wrapper object around `Typeface` that tracks this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the sources, you will see that the default ones are created with style `DEFAULT` (*), so:

```
Typeface paintTf = paint.getTypeface();
Typeface.SERIF.equals(Typeface.create(paintTf, Typeface.DEFAULT));
```

might do the job (here I check is family is serif).

NB: (*) is not true for DEFAULT_BOLD.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to [use font from Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml), so that you can simply compare the type face by equals()

example:

```
Typeface toCompare = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.my_font);
assert tf.equals(toCompare)
```