# Calculating width of a string on Android

Tags: android, text-rendering

I need to know width of text string given font handle (or font name + font size + font style data).

in Windows I used to use GetTextExtentPoint()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this code

```
 Rect bounds = new Rect(); 
 Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
 textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds); 
 int height = bounds.height(); 
 int width = bounds.width();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get TypeFace of TextView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTypeface()
but it's hard to get font family, check also this:
[Check the family of a Typeface object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542513/check-the-family-of-a-typeface-object-in-android)