# Android get toast position

Tags: android, android-toast

I'm able to fetch every (default) toast message, but I want to add the app icon to it. How can I get the position from the toast view/widget?

My toast catcher is an `AccessibilityService` and I was hoping that the `AccessibilityEvent` has something useful in it, but I didn't find a property with the needed data.

Edit: CyanogenMod added it and I want to implement it into stock android with my app.

[image: Example toast]

Comment: you need the toast position or you wanna add an icon to it?

Comment: Because the toast ist from a different app, I'm not allowed to edit the toast. My idea was to overlay the app icon and because of that I need the position. Is there an other way?

Comment: sorry but i'm not sure i got it, so you wanna hide the toast by overlaying it with another view, right?

Comment: I added an example image, how I want it ;)

Comment: ooook got it,i have an idea but i'm not sure it will work, let me post it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of Toast Message

```
setGravity(int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset)
```

As you know your Toast message position you can simply set your icon position accordingly [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setGravity%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: the toast is not in his app, so he can't access it with setGravity :S

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try **Custom toast** ?

Screen shot attached for the same.

[image]

**custom_toast_view.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toastParent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F08080"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In **Java class**:

```
private void displayToast(){
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_view, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastParent));
   ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
   image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
   text.setText("Hello! This is a custom toast!");
   Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
   toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.setView(layout);
   toast.show();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: My app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mars3142.android.toaster) will catch every toast. So, I can't use custom layouts. I don't want to disable the original toast and show a custom one

Answer (score 0):

With the following code you can get default Toast Y offset from bottom of the screen:

```
int i = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("toast_y_offset", "dimen", "android");
int bottomOffset = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(i);
```

Then just place your image at the bottom of the screen with bottom padding == `bottomOffset`.

Answer on "where do I get the left position?":

Toast uses android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" to align text and default text size. So you can calculate how many space this text would take (if you know what the exact text would be) : [Calculating width of a string on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355950/calculating-width-of-a-string-on-android) . Then left offset can be calculated as `(screenWidth - textWidth) / 2`.

Comment: And where do I get the left position?

Comment: This could be the only possible way (manual calculation), if I can't read the data from elsewhere.