# Detect if a unicode character is supported?

Tags: android, unicode

I'm trying to put together a small android app that can randomly return an emoji to the user. My intention is to just use actual unicode emoji characters, and return them as unicode string characters.

I built a full array of unicode strings that could be randomly chosen from, and many will display correctly. However some are showing up as unsupported characters (a rectangle with an x through it).

Obviously not every platform will support every unicode emoji character, but if possible I'd like a way to determine what is and isn't a supported character. The ideal would be to query for a list of supported characters, but being able to test individual characters would also do the job just fine.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: @Maragues Unfortunately not, I resigned myself to just have a constant array where I manually defined the safe emoji that I could expect to work.

Comment: It looks like Android 23 does include something (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#hasGlyph(java.lang.String)), but the code invokes a native function, so I guess I'm out of luck. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @Maragues, why are you out of luck? Is it because you need to support pre-API 23 or because `hasGlyph` is not working for you?

Comment: I don't even remember what I was trying to do :(

Answer (score 6):

Also check out `Paint.hasGlyph(String)`, which was added in API level 23. You can use this to test if a character like an emoji has a glyph available.

This is what the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#hasGlyph(java.lang.String)) says:

> `boolean hasGlyph (String string)`
>
> Determine whether the typeface set on the paint has a glyph supporting
> the string. The simplest case is when the string contains a single
> character, in which this method determines whether the font has the
> character. In the case of multiple characters, the method returns true
> if there is a single glyph representing the ligature. For example, if
> the input is a pair of regional indicator symbols, determine whether
> there is an emoji flag for the pair.
>
> Finally, if the string contains a variation selector, the method only
> returns true if the fonts contains a glyph specific to that variation.
>
> Checking is done on the entire fallback chain, not just the immediate
> font referenced.

See also

- [How to detect emoji support on Android by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194616/how-to-detect-emoji-support-on-android-by-code)

Comment: That is on Paint.

Answer (score 5):

So, when you talk about a character being "unsupported", it sounds like what you mean is that the current font doesn't have a glyph for the character (and either the application doesn't have fallback logic to find a different font that *does*, or the system doesn't have *any* font that does).

In regular Java, this is pretty easy: given an instance of `java.awt.Font`, you can see if it has a glyph for a given Unicode character by using [the `canDisplay` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay-char-).

The Android APIs, for whatever reason, don't seem to expose a way to figure out what font you're actually working with. (`android.graphics.Typeface` keeps that information private: see ["Check the family of a Typeface object in Android"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13542513/978917).) However, you might at least try something like `new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 12)` to get a basic 12-point sans-serif font. You'll want to test, of course, to see if that gives a usable approximation for the emoji that the *real* font will be able to display.

Comment: You are exactly right about what I mean. Thanks for the info! It seems that the Android api doesn't include `java.awt.Font` at all, so I can't import it and use that method. But I'll see what I can do with a Typeface, and try wrangling it into a more usable font or possibly just trying to set a default font where I know when glyphs aren't supported.

Comment: Oh, weird -- I didn't realize that Android omitted parts of the JDK. (I'm not an Android dev, if you can't tell. :-P )

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Character.isDefined` to check if a character is defined in the version of Unicode on the device.

Comment: Ah, this is a good lead. Thanks! Unfortunately it's only occasionally catching problems. There's a lot of false positives, which makes me think it wasn't properly implemented in Android.

Comment: `Character.isDefined` means "does the JVM know what kind of character this is?" (e.g. whether it's whitespace, or a digit, or . . .), whereas the OP wants "does the current font have a glyph for this character?".